# What is memory level error with slow transaction message?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory

I am working on map-view app.My app did't crash or memory leaks but it's close after 10 minute with following message.

> 2012-01-20 03:24:48.510 MY Map[767:707] sqlite error 5 [database is locked]
>   2012-01-20 03:24:48.615 My Map[767:707] sqlite prepare statement retry was successful.  Continuing.
>   2012-01-20 03:30:47.690 MY Map[767:707] slow transaction: time was 0.41229 seconds
>   2012-01-20 03:30:48.520 MY Map[767:707] Received memory warning. Level=1
>   2012-01-20 03:31:13.664 MY Map[767:707] slow transaction: time was 0.306271 seconds
>   2012-01-20 03:31:14.606 MY Map[767:707] Received memory warning. Level=2
>   2012-01-20 03:31:15.390 MY Map[767:707] slow transaction: time was 0.287666 seconds
>   2012-01-20 03:31:44.897 MY Map[767:707] Received memory warning. Level=1
>   2012-01-20 03:31:56.339 MY Map[767:707] Received memory warning. Level=2

This message arrive after 10 minute of continue using  app.I know memory level 3 warning is critical condition.But my app did't leak any memory or error.

Please Help me,
Thanks In advance.